# Duplicate Linux file user, group and permissions attribute

Tags: permissions, shell, files

How can I copy all the files attributes of file B, into file A in command line ?
(A & B are differents)

ex:
A user user 666,
B root root 770

result --> A root root 770

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chown --reference=B A
chmod --reference=B A
```

This works on Linux/GNU.  On other systems you might need to go a more complicated route, or install the GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `chmod --reference=B A`